# Interfacing with an application that doesn't have a native API

Tags: interface

I'm trying to make a game bot for a game that doesn't have an programmatic interface. For example, how would I make a program that plays Window's Minesweeper game? Not make my own Minesweeper game and program a solution to it but rather window's game. I'm just looking for the methodology that would be used to for a program like this. Would I need to use a screen capture software and define what a group of pixels means and interface that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Windows application, you can use `SendMessage` to send emulated mouse and keyboard commands to another application.

You will need to get the `HWND`, which you can get with `FindWindow` or equivalent (your Windows version will affect this, since on older versions of Windows you iterate through window handles looking for the executable name, while on Windows 8 and beyond some of the applications aren't visible without special handling - MSDN will have documentation on this).

Grab a screen capture of the screen of non-DirectX applications by using `GetDC`, then `BitBlt` to copy the screen to a bitmap of your own, then `ReleaseDC`.  E.g. with Minesweeper, if your "bot" remembers the previous screenshot, do a diff between that and the current in order to find locations that have changed since the last turn.

You should be able to use a debugger or a process monitor tool while you play to identify the Window messages that you will need to send.

For other applications/platforms, you will often find that a similar approach works, since these are the highest level hooks for debuggers, system monitors, etc (and there are lower, but those can cause problems if you mess with them).

For web applications specifically, the cross-site scripting limitations will make it difficult to use this approach.  There are two normal ways to make this work for web applications:
1) embed a web browser control in your "bot" application and inject additional javascript on page load (since the application controls are dynamic), but that gets a little more difficult since you can have multiple layers and multiple frames, as well as additional APIs (HTML5, WebGL, etc).
2) use a stand-alone html/javascript engine to render/execute only as much of the client-side code as necessary, and then modify the state directly (for example, if you want to emulate a button press that posts to a remote server, just use the javascript engine to call the button handler function directly.

Any solution will be dependent on the application to be emulated, so you won't be able to build a universal "bot", if that is what you intend.

Note that OSes protect their applications, so getting access to the memory of a running application is going to be dangerous if you aren't extremely careful, and figuring out what the memory does will be nearly impossible.  Consider that Windows dynamically loads most DLLs to random base addresses as a security measure, and applications generally use `GlobalAlloc` (or a non-Windows equivalent) to store the bulk of their data, so even if you find the data you care about, it won't be in the same place the next time you run the application.

This is generally legal (as in you won't go to jail) although your membership or software license can be suspended, and in extreme cases, you can be fined or sued.  Client applications aren't likely to have any limits like that, so on those, the worst you can do is cause the application to crash or hang if you confuse it sufficiently with weird messages.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be illegal, but the programming challenge is worth it.

I think there are two methods to do it.
You could use a library like openCV to recognize patterns and use it, but it would be slow, so there is a limit to little games where time is not important.

Or, you could permanently code a soft that reads the game process RAM to analyze it. I think Cheat engine works like this.

Comment: As long as you do not try to reverse engineer the target game this should be legal in general. The target game will only see mouse clicks and keyboard hits and will have no clue where these come from. However some licenses explicily prohibit automating (e.g. scripting ebay).

Answer (score 0):

For capturing the target application's window you don't neccesarly need low level Win32 API calls. You should be able to do this with .NET. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12898/Screen-Capturing 
Once you have your target `HWND` (see Matt Jordan's answer), you can create a .NET Control with `Control.FromHWND()`. Then `capture()` the window in a `Bitmap`.

For the automation stuff: In a simple game like minesweeper the items you need to look at are organized as a grid. You could just scan the Bitmap read out from the target window and examine pixels at specific positions. The general case needs more sophisticated tools. OpenCV, as suggested by girod_s should be a good guess.

Everything else has already been said by Matt Jordan.

If you want be sure to stay on the legal side, don't attempt to work directly on the target application's RAM. You still should have a look at the license terms of that application however (see my comment on girod_s's answer).